# Force BitLocker to trust current state of laptop

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, encryption, bitlocker

I have a laptop that came with Windows 10 Home, but for some reason its disk is encrypted with BitLocker. I wanted to use Linux, so I installed Ubuntu 18.04 (dual-boot with Windows on a seperate partition). Now, every time I boot into Windows, BitLocker asks me to enter my BitLocker recovery key. I know this key, but it is a very difficult-to-remember 48 digit number, and it is a pain to enter it before each boot. During the Ubuntu instalation, I was prompted to create a BitLocker password, but I am not able to enter this anywhere.

How can I get BitLocker to trust the current setup of my computer, so it doesn't ask for a recovery key every time?